# Solving recurrence relation T(n) = T(n - 1) + 3n substitution method.

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

Given:
$$
T(n) = \begin{cases}
4, & n = 1\\
T(n - 1) + 3n, & n > 1\\
\end{cases}
$$
I was trying to prove that $T(n) = O(n^2)$ using the substitution method.
I guess that the solution is $O(n^2)$, and I have to prove by induction that $\exists c > 0, n_0 \ni \forall n \ge n_0, \space T(n) = cn^2$.

So, I started like this:
$$
T(n) \le c(n - 1)^2 + 3n = cn^2 - 2cn + c +3n = cn^2 -n(2c \space - \space 3) + c
$$
Since I am trying to prove that $cn^2 - n(2c - 3) + c = O(n^2)$, I continued like this:
$$
cn^2 - n(2c - 3) + c \le cn^2\\
-n(2c - 3) + c \le 0\\
n(2c - 3) \ge c\\
n \ge \frac{c}{2c - 3}
$$

This result means that $T(n) = O(n^2), \space \space \forall n\ge \frac{c}{2c-3}$.
This proof is correct, because the last condition doesn't "force" c to grow with n, but n has to be greater than some fixed constant, is that correct?
For the sake of the argument, if I had $\frac{c}{2c-3} \ge n$, the proof would have failed because this condition "forces" c to grow with n, right?

Comment: $T(n) = O(n^2) \Rightarrow \exists c > 0, n_0 > 0 \: \forall n \geq n_0 T(n) \le c n^2$.

Comment: $cn^2 - n(2c - 3) + c = O(n^2) \Rightarrow cn^2 - n(2c - 3) + c \le c_2 n^2$. There is no reason the constants should be the same.

Comment: $T(n)=4+3(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1)$ which clearly is $O(n^2)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that we don't generally use induction to find $O$ bounds, and the reason is trivial, you have that $T(n) \le c n^2$ for $n \ge n_0$ only, but for $n < n_0$, you dont have $T(n) \le c n^2$, so an induction argument won't work.

The way you find O bounds for functions specified by recursion is by unfolding the recursion (here you can use induction) or alternatively using Master Theorem.

Comment: I do not understand, the substitution method is used to find lower/upper bound of a recurrence and this method work like the induction method, to be clear, it's basis is the induction principle, am I wrong?

Comment: When you write some function $f$ is $O(g)$, then $f$ is less than c times $g$ ONLY for HIGH values of $n$ (formally we denote this by saying $\exists n_0 \: n \geq n_0 \Rightarrow f \le c \cdot g$. But when you are trying to use induction to prove a property, you need the property to hold for all values of $n$, UNLESS you start your induction from $n=n_0$ and not $n=1$.

Comment: Mh, this put me in a more difficult situation.
The substitution method works like this and is used in this way.
How can I prove it using this method?